# nginx says forbidden, user nginx at fedora

Tags: nginx, permissions, fedora

I'm confused

```
2014/05/12 09:36:51 [error] 25928#0: *1 open() "/home/dev/OpenWrt-ImageBuilder-brcm47xx-for-linux-x86_64/packages/test.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 128.68.154.57, server: localhost, request: "GET /test.html HTTP/1.1"
```

here is permissions

```
[root@vsfedora OpenWrt-ImageBuilder-brcm47xx-for-linux-x86_64]# namei -l /home/dev/OpenWrt-ImageBuilder-brcm47xx-for-linux-x86_64/packages/test.html
f: /home/dev/OpenWrt-ImageBuilder-brcm47xx-for-linux-x86_64/packages/test.html
dr-xr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root home
drwxrwx--- dev  dev  dev
drwxr-xr-x dev  dev  OpenWrt-ImageBuilder-brcm47xx-for-linux-x86_64
drwxr-xr-x dev  dev  packages
-rw-rw-r-- dev  dev  test.html
```

here is group

```
dev:x:1000:nginx
```

nginx worker process working as nginx user

```
[root@vsfedora ~]# ps aux|grep nginx
root     26494  0.0  0.3 111588  3796 ?        Ss   11:07   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
nginx    26495  0.0  0.5 111932  5116 ?        S    11:07   0:00 nginx: worker process
```

server section in nginx.conf:

```
server {
        location / {
        autoindex  on;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
}
```

symlink is also fine

```
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 0 0   65 May 12 10:10 packages -> /home/dev/OpenWrt-ImageBuilder-brcm47xx-for-linux-x86_64/packages
```

Comment: As this is not related to programming, I'm flagging it for migration.

Comment: `drwxrwx--- dev  dev  dev` misses last `x`

Comment: last x is for others, not needed

Comment: Oh, missed last part. Have you restarted nginx?

Comment: seems like it's SELinux issue, audit.log says "type=AVC msg=audit(1399879586.183:2081199): avc:  denied  { search } for  pid=26495 comm="nginx" name="dev" dev="dm-1" ino=269277 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t:s0 tclass=dir"
    
looking for resolution

Comment: got a solution here [link](http://axilleas.me/en/blog/2013/selinux-policy-for-nginx-and-gitlab-unix-socket-in-fedora-19/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's a SELinux issue

tail /var/log/audit/audit.log

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1399879586.183:2081199): avc:  denied  { search } for  pid=26495 comm="nginx" name="dev" dev="dm-1" ino=269277 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t:s0 tclass=dir
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1399879586.183:2081199): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=no exit=-13 a0=7fdd65ed2219 a1=800 a2=0 a3=0 items=0 ppid=26494 pid=26495 auid=4294967295 uid=996 gid=1000 euid=996 suid=996 fsuid=996 egid=1000 sgid=1000 fsgid=1000 ses=4294967295 tty=(none) comm="nginx" exe="/usr/sbin/nginx" subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)
```

detailed explanation and resolution can be found [here](http://axilleas.me/en/blog/2013/selinux-policy-for-nginx-and-gitlab-unix-socket-in-fedora-19/)

Answer (score 0):

Per documentation on [`user`](http://nginx.org/r/user) directive, nginx uses group name equal to user name if you omit group name. So you have to explicitly use `user nginx dev;` in your `nginx.conf`.

Comment: this not helped, anyway group `nginx` also contains user `dev`. nginx is restarted